# Baking texture | Issues | Low Quality

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I've been trying to solve this problem for several days, but I can't figure it out.
I made a model of a house. My model is made up of multiple meshes: this is intentional, as having a single mesh I think would have made baking even more complicated.

So I'll just take the roof of my house as an example. As you can see from the image, the quality rendered by baking is very poor, yet I used a 4096x4096 image for the baking. I just can't figure out where the problem is. I did the Smart UV project with a very small Island Margin.

This is only the difference in the color map [image]

This is color map + normal + displacement (on the right the baked texture) [image]

What else can I do to improve the quality? I purposely separated the meshes of my model to have better UV Mapping, but it doesn't seem to work

Thank you in advance